# floating to right div not showing chosen width

Tags: html, width, floating

I have an div that is floating to the right with a width of 740px set up in css. Displaying in the browser I don't see a 740px width, what is going wrong? Placing a H1 text inside doesn't make the div 740px wide; it only shows the width of the text.

While making it float to the left, it has the total width of 740px. What am I missing here of the concept of floating?

```
<div id='banner'>
  <h1>Website Title</h1>
</div>

div#banner
{   
padding: 0px;
margin: 5px;


border-style: solid;
border-width: 1px;
border-color: blue;

width: 740 px;
height: 310 px;
display: inline-block;
float: right;
text-align:left;
}
```

I can fix it with the use of min-width, but that feels more like a fix then solving the problem why the div isn't at 740px wide.

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your css problem you use  width: 740 px;
    height: 310 px;

please remove space 740 and  px

and use `width:740px;` & `height:310px;`

try this

http://jsfiddle.net/7CCDK/2/

```
div#banner
{   
padding: 0px;
margin: 5px;


border-style: solid;
border-width: 1px;
border-color: blue;

width: 740px;
height: 310px;
display: inline-block;
float: right;
text-align:left;
}
```

Comment: That was the bottleneck! Thank you sir (Y)